# Android Tabs в диалогах

Tags: android, java

Создаю разметку для диалогового окна. Там создаю табы с содержимым. Но когда использую эту разметку в диалоговом окне, то табов как таковых нет, а все содержимое накладывается друг на друга. Подскажите что не так?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <TimePicker
                        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <DatePicker
                        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:calendarViewShown="false"
                        android:spinnersShown="true" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, выложите разметку

Comment: @SuperCreeper обновила вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде вы используете FrameLayout, он предоставляет внутри себя место только для одного элемента (последующие как раз будут накладываться) , а у вас их там несколько. Держите правильную разметку.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        </TabWidget>

                    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                                    <TimePicker
                    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                                    <DatePicker
                    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:calendarViewShown="false"
                    android:spinnersShown="true" />
                                </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Теперь все друг над другом) на табов так и нет...:(